# Configuring Prometheus JMX exporter for Hadoop2

Tags: hadoop, prometheus, jmx

I am trying to scrape metrics from following Hadoop2 daemons running on ec2 instance using Prometheus JMX exporter:

- hadoop namenode
- hadoop datanode
- yarn resourcemanager
- yarn nodemanager

I am trying to run JMX exporter as a java agent with all the four daemons. For this I have added EXTRA_JAVA_OPTS in `hadoop-env.sh` and `yarn-env.sh` :

```
export HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="$HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS -javaagent:/home/ec2-user/jmx_exporter/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.10.jar=9102:/home/ec2-user/jmx_exporter/prometheus_config.yml"
export HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS="$HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS -javaagent:/home/ec2-user/jmx_exporter/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.10.jar=9102:/home/ec2-user/jmx_exporter/prometheus_config.yml"
export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_OPTS="$YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_OPTS -javaagent:/home/ec2-user/jmx_exporter/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.10.jar=9102:/home/ec2-user/jmx_exporter/prometheus_config.yml"
export YARN_NODEMANAGER_OPTS="$YARN_NODEMANAGER_OPTS -javaagent:/home/ec2-user/jmx_exporter/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.10.jar=9102:/home/ec2-user/jmx_exporter/prometheus_config.yml"
```

Sample prometheus_config.yml for a resourcemanager metric NumAllSources is as follows :

```
rules:
 - pattern: Hadoop<service=ResourceManager, name=MetricsSystem, sub=Stats><>NumAllSources
   name: sources
   labels:
    app_id: "hadoop_rm"
```

I am getting the following exception when I restart the resourcemanager or other daemons with new configs and java_opts :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:382)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:397)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Collector already registered that provides name: jmx_scrape_duration_seconds
at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry.register(CollectorRegistry.java:54)
at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.Collector.register(Collector.java:128)
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

While @chanhou's solution will work, I wanted to keep my edits in `hadoop-env.sh`, so I went with

```sh
if ! grep -q <<<"$HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS" jmx_prometheus_javaagent; then
        HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="$HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS -javaagent:/home/caesarli/platform/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar=11099:/home/caesarli/platform/hadoop-2.8.4/etc/hadoop/jmx-name.yaml"
fi
```

and similar for the `HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS`.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `-javaagent` opts is declare multiple times in `$HADOOP_OPTS` when you call `/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode` and `hadoop-daemon.sh` will eventually call `/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs` to start related service.

During the process, it will source multiple times of `hadoop-config.sh` and if you `echo $HADOOP_OPTS` in the shell script `/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs` then you will find multiple `-javaagent` there.

A workaround is declare `HADOOP_OPTS=$HADOOP_OPTS -javaagent:...` in `/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs` to ensure only one `-javaagent` appear in `HADOOP_OPTS`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you are using same ports (9102) for all the registrations, changing ports will help.